# PrimeFaces input text enter key

Tags: jquery, primefaces, jsf-2

JSF 2.0,PrimeFaces 5.3

Hello, I have developed a navigation control (using jquery) that when you press the enter key in some component of the form (input text, autocomplete, etc) Focus jump to the next component, so you can browse without use the mouse. One of my component it's a input text area so I need replace the enter key by other to do a line break. I have researched and find out that I can use next code to catch the enter key in input text area.

```
<p:inputText id="commentInput" rendered="#{foo.rendered}" 
value="#{foo.value}"
onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { onchange(); return false; }">
<f:ajax event="change" listener="#{foo.test}" />
```

Well my question is, It's possible using other key combination to produce a line break in the input text area? Maybe <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> key or similar.
This application is a port of other desktop application, so I need copy the behaviour.

**Update with solution proposed by @DavidFlorez**

```
onkeyup="if (event.ctrlKey &amp;&amp; event.keyCode == 13) {this.value = this.value.slice(0, $(this).caret().begin)+'\n'+this.value.slice($(this).caret()‌​.begin);}"
```

When I start to write in the inputTextarea I get the next error:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list**

I check ) but I see that all are closing. I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> key but nothing happens.

Comment: This is an inputText, not an 'input text area' as you state in your text.

Comment: InputTextArea have onkeypress event to, the example is not my code. My big problem is how to replicate line break with other key combination.

Comment: try with `event.shiftKey` adding a text break where your cursor is `if (event.keyCode == 13 && event.shiftKey){ this.value = this.value.slice(0, $(this).caret().begin)+'\n'+this.value.slice($(this).caret().begin)}`

Comment: @DavidFlorez I add your code but doesn't work if (event.ctrlKey &amp;&amp; event.keyCode == 13) {this.value = this.value.slice(0, $(this).caret().begin)+'\n'+this.value.slice($(this).caret()‌​‌​.begin);}. Sorry but I don't know how to format code in comment

Comment: did it throw any error?

Comment: @Chema: using 'backticks' (the key above the tab usually) formats the code a little in comments

Answer (score 0):

Using @DavidFlorez solution I have modified my code:

```
<p:inputTextarea id="input" immediate="#{cc.attrs.inmediate}" value="#{cc.attrs.bean[cc.attrs.property]}" 
                tabindex="#{groupOfControl.getNextIndex(cc)}" maxlength="#{cc.attrs.maxLength}" 
                disabled="#{cc.attrs.disabled}" binding="#{cc.attrs.binding}" onkeyup="keyOverTextArea(event, '#{cc.clientId}Var')" 
                required="#{cc.attrs.require}" styleClass="#{cc.attrs.styleClass}" 
           rows="#{cc.attrs.row}" cols="#{cc.attrs.cols}" autoResize="#{cc.attrs.autoResize}" widgetVar="#{cc.clientId}Var"
           style="width:#{cc.attrs.width}%;resize:none">
        <composite:insertChildren />      
     </p:inputTextarea>
```

The onkeyup attribute call a jquery function where I have written:

```
function keyOverTextArea(event, widgetVar){
    if(event.keyCode == 13 && event.ctrlKey){
        var component = $(document.getElementById(PF(widgetVar).id));
        component.val(component.val().slice(0, component.caret().begin)+'\n'+component.val().slice(component.caret().begin));
        return false;
    }

    if ((event.which == 9 && !event.shiftKey) || event.which == 13){
        var idNextComponent = findComponent.findIdNextComponent(PF(widgetVar).id, null, true);
        PrimeFaces.focus(idNextComponente);
    }
}
```